# Como setar uma Struct como NULL em C?

Tags: c, struct

Estou querendo verificar se ha conteúdo algum na `struct` então queria inicializar as variáveis como `NULL`, pois se fossem iguais a `NULL` saberia que não foram criadas.

trechos:

Struct:

```
struct  Fila
{

    int         capacidade;
    float       *dados;
    int         primeiro;
    int         ultimo;
    int         nItens;

};
```

inicialização:

```
struct  Fila
PPFila          =   (Fila)NULL,  <--- Erro de incompatibilidade
AUTFila         =   (Fila)NULL;  <--- Erro de incompatibilidade
```

Criação:

```
if(PPFila   ==  (Fila)NULL)
{

    //
    //  Cria as filas que gerencias as o envio das threads
    //
    criarFila(&PPFila,  20);
}
```

Alguém tem alguma dica como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Lucas, por favor, use a tag "c++" apenas para problemas de C++. C é uma linguagem diferente.

Comment: @PabloAlmeida o problema também cabe para C++, se ele deseja uma solução tanto para C, quanto para C++, ele pode fazer isto.

Comment: @LucasFernandes você quer que fique a *tag* C++?

Comment: @bigown O título da pergunta pede uma solução em C. Além disso, C++ tem jeitos diferentes de lidar com coisas que estão sendo feitas no código. Uma resposta em C++ tenderia a educar o AP sobre essas diferenças, e isso pode ser uma perda de tempo caso a tag tenha sido colocada por ignorância.

Comment: @bigown pode deixar assim, meu interesse é mesmo em C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não é possível setar uma struct com NULL da forma como está declarada.

```
Fila f = NUll;

error: invalid initializer.
```

Se quiser atribuir NULL à uma struct deve declará-la como ponteiro:

```
Fila * PPFila = NULL,
     * AUTFila = NULL;
```

Comment: Usando o gcc e clang, ao atribuir um NULL a um inteiro, ele só me manda um warning, mas cria um executável assim mesmo (_**warning**: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'int' with an expression of type 'void *' [-Wint-conversion]_)

Comment: @Amadeus Qual é o comando que está utilizando para compilar o programa? estou usando o gcc e não deu esse warning, poderia postar o código que está usando para aparecer esse warning?

Comment: Primeiramente, o meu gcc é a versão 6.1.1. Segundo, usei o básico mesmo `gcc -o x x.c`, mas vc pode tentar com a opção `-Wall`. No [ideone](http://ideone.com/sK50r0) nem mesmo gera warning

Comment: A única diferença que é que meu gcc está na versão 4.9.2, poderia mostrar o código que está usando para gerar esse warning?

Comment: desculpe, não tinha visto o código. Então, como falei no post para usar o NULL deve-se declarar a váriavel como ponteiro. Ponteiros são declarados com '*' antes do nome. Neste código a varável está declarada como inteiro, não suportando o uso do NULL.

Comment: Para mais informações sobre a utilização de ponteiros recomendo a leitura [deste artigo](http://www.cprogressivo.net/2013/03/Como-declarar-inicializar-e-usar-ponteiros-e-a-constante-NULL-em-C.html)

Comment: Você não entendeu a colocação. É errado colocar NULL para variáveis primárias, exemplo `int`. O que estou colocando é que o compilador nem sempre vê isso como um erro. No caso do ideone, conforme colocado no comentário acima, não gerou nem mesmo o **warning**. Então, a expressão "Não é possível atribuir NULL à este inteiro" não é verdade. É possível sim, só que não é correto

Comment: Sim, pode-se atribuir, pois o endereço de memória, em um programa de 32 bits, é um inteiro. pode-se inclusive usar o seguinte comando: numero = (int) &numero; para guardar na variável o endereço dela. Não saberia dizer um uso prático para isso. mas é possível

Comment: A discussão já está ficando longa e logo vão cortar todos os comentários, por isso, vou apenas reafirmar o que já disse: Sua colocação no post está errada. É possível atribuir NULL a uma variável do tipo int, por exemplo. Mas **não é correto**. Infelizmente o compilador nem sempre vai te ajudar nisso. Até agora, só vi um _warning_ sendo gerado. Comentando o seu último comentário, endereços de memória normalmente são do tipo `unsigned int` para evitar problemas com extensão do sinal.

Comment: Entendi o problema, editei a resposta. Obrigado

Answer (score 4):

`stddef.h` define `NULL` como:

```
#define NULL ((void *)0)
```

Por isso fazer um cast de `NULL` para `Fila`, que nem é um tipo neste código, ou atribuir `NULL` para uma variável de tipo primitivo é "errado". "`NULL` não é um valor", é um ponteiro sem tipo para o endereço 0.

Use um ponteiro para a sua estrutura, assim pode inicializá-la como nula.

```
struct Fila * PPFila = NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Bom, para a inicialização, o que gosto de fazer é usar o `memset` para colocar todas as variáveis em ZERO.

Exemplo:

```
struct  Fila PPFila, AUTFila;
memset(&PPFile, 0, sizeof(PPFila));
memset(&AUTFile, 0, sizeof(AUTFila));
```

Para saber se tá inicializado ou não, vc pode usar algum parâmetro de sua estrutura que diz isso, ou criar um específico para dizer se já foi inicializado. No seu caso, parece que o campo `nItens` faz exatamente esse papel. Assim, para a verificação:

```
if(PPFila.nItens == 0)
{
    //
    //  Cria as filas que gerencias as o envio das threads
    //
    criarFila(&PPFila,  20);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, ajudou bastante

Comment: O que fazer no caso de a fila já estar criada e tiver 0 itens? Isso é possível? vai precisar ter um controle rigoroso à isso.

Comment: Para se ter uma ideia, acesse '*PPFila.dados' no if, isso acaba gerando um erro de execução, e travando o programa.

Comment: olhando por esse ponto, parece fazer todo sentido

Comment: e o que acontecera se tentar cria-la novamente se estiver ja criada mas com 0 elementos?

Comment: @Pilati Por isso que disse na resposta: "ou criar um específico para dizer se já foi inicializado". Se na estrutura não existe uma variável que pode ser utilizada para esse papel, crie uma, talvez algo do gênero `int inicializada;` e depois verifique se é zero, se for, inicialize e coloque 1. Dei apenas uma sugestão no caso dele, que, agora, me parece que é melhor usar a variável `capacidade`

Comment: @Amadeus Realmente a capacidade parece ser o melhor campo criado para essa finalidade, não tem sentido uma fila ter uma capacidade 0.

Comment: @LucasFernandes Pelo que notei a estrutura tem um ponteiro para float, então se já tiver sido criada a fila e for criar novamente a referencia para o ponteiro antigo será perdida, ocasionando assim os famosos vazamentos de memória